# [java.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, vector, classcastexception

I'm obtaining a Vector from a product's API.

```
Vector<?> dataVector = dataAPI.getReturnVector();
```

The vector is expected to contain Strings as value. I'm able to print the size of the vector as 2. But for some reason I'm not able to iterate and print the values.

I tried

```
Iterator<?> iter = dataVector.iterator();

while( iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

I always end up getting a

```
[java.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I used

```
iter.next().getClass().getName()
```

and it turned out to be `java.lang.String` only.

I googled a bit and found a similar problem at http://prideafrica.blogspot.com/2007/01/javalangclasscastexception.html

I tried to set the generics as `String[]`, but ended up with the same error.

If the vector contains `java.lang.String`, why do I get this cast exception? How can I print the actual values?

Kindly provide your suggestions.

Comment: Where did that semicolon come from?

Comment: Did the error message perhaps start with an open brace like `[java.lang.String;`? That would be the internal name of a String array.

Comment: Oh yes, it started with an open brace[. Sorry for missing that. I didn't know that it would make a difference.

Comment: What is doing the casting? Is it the iterator?

Comment: Which kind of "product API" is that? May there be a Java bytecode version mismatch?

Comment: @βнɛƨнǤʋяʋиɢ Iterator does the casting.

Comment: @Viruzzo Its a networking product API, and I was able to use the other API's without any problem. The javadocs doesn't say much too...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the API is not returning a Vector of Strings but a Vector of String[].

You should be able to iterate through the vector and then, for each element, loop through the array.

```
Iterator<String[]> iter = dataVector.iterator();

while( iter.hasNext()) {
    String[] array = iter.next();
    for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
       System.out.println(i + ": " + array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will work. in my case, as you said the Vector was returning String[]. For some reasom, the api method did not 'fill in' the String arrays as expected...

Answer (score 4):

Try compare their classLoaders. If they are different, then this Exception occur.

```
StringClass1.getClassLoader()==StringClass2.getClassLoader();
```

Comment: Looks like something is trying to cast an array of `String`s to `String`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use an iterator. You could just use the `elementAt(index)` method of `Vector`s to print the values. Use a `For` loop to get the indices of the `Vector`.

Example:

```
Vector<?> dataVector = dataAPI.getReturnVector();
for(int i = 0; i < dataVector.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(dataVector.elementAt(i));
}
```

If you are getting a strange answer (of numbers and letters), you getting a `String[]` object. That means you will have use the built-in method of `Arrays` to print the `String[]` array. See the comments below.

Comment: It prints [Ljava.lang.String;@25a091[Ljava.lang.String;@50a11a

Comment: @whoopy_whale: You can do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataVector.elementAt(i)));`.

Comment: @βнɛƨнǤʋяʋиɢ To use Arrays.toString, I had to use the generics as Vector<String[]> and the output was [][]

Comment: @Roshnal Tried with Arrays method, and it prints [] [] (empty arrays)

Comment: Ok...figured out... The API is returning a vector of size two, and the values are two String arrays. Those String arrays are expected to contain values, and in this case for some reason, was empty. Thats a problem with the api call only. But as you all said, the cast exception was due to the String[] and String. Thanks for all the help!